# Измерить скорость движения мыши Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

На тачскрине можно легко измерить скорость движения пальца

```
foreach(Touch th in input.touches)
{
th.deltaPosition.x / Time.deltaTime
}
```

Как это сделать для мышки? Желательно с подобным же кодом, чтобы можно было сделать универсальный метод измерения скорости для мышки и тача.

Comment: Это точно работает? Нужно взять предыдущую координату (Мышки /пальца) отнять текущую координату и поделить на  Time.deltaTime.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Прекрасно работает! 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-deltaPosition.html
Тут даже указано что можно использовать это для скорости. 
Предыдущая координата  с текущей - очевидное решение. Для тача это происходит в автоматическом режиме, видимо т.к. Input.touches возвращает массив. А вот с мышкой другого варианта кроме как сохранять позиции n и n-1 и смотреть разницу между ними нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В добавление к ответу автора (прокомментировать не могу, не хватает баллов репутации):

```
Vector2 lastMousepos = Input.MousePosition;
void Update()
{    
AxisX = ((Input.MousePosition.x - lastMousepos.x) / Time.deltaTime) / Screen.Width;
AxisY = ((Input.MousePosition.y - lastMousepos.y) / Time.deltaTime) /Screen.Height;
lastMousepos = Input.MousePosition;
}
```

минус одна проверка условия в каждом кадре

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете посчитать разницу (дельту) между начальной и конечной позицией, это и будет ваше расстояние, которое нужно поделить на время.

Comment: Возможно вы имели ввиду между позицией в предыдущем кадре и в текущем? Можете расписать это подробнее?

Comment: Навскидку - вы можете получать координаты курсора в Update / FixedUpdate (лучше в Update, конечно), записывать их в какой-нибудь Vector2 LastCoordinates, и вычислять разницу, затем считать скорость.

Comment: Ремарку "лучше в Update, конечно" прошу считать недействительной - это зависит от того, что конкретно вам нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Что насчёт `Input.GetAxis()`?

```
Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
```

Для большей информативности:

> Возвращает значение по axisName виртуальной оси.
>
> Для ввода с клавиатуры или джойстика значение будет лежать в диапазоне -1…1. If the axis is setup to be delta mouse movement, the mouse delta is multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1…1.
>
> Это не зависит от частоты кадров. При использовании данного значения нет необходимости беспокоиться об изменении частоты кадров.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float horizontalSpeed = 2.0F;
    public float verticalSpeed = 2.0F;
    void Update() {
        float h = horizontalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float v = verticalSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
       transform.Rotate(v, h, 0);
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).

(На всякий случай, настроить чувствительность можно в Edit → Project Settings → Input.)

Comment: Ответ крайне малоинформативен. Можете расписать чуть подробнее?

Comment: Разве это измерения скорости? Мы просто получаем значения осей

Comment: @Dmitrii, нет, для мыши это скорость.

Answer (score 1):

Делаем так

```
Vector2 lastMousepos;
void Update(){    
if (lastMousepos == Vector2.zero)
    {
        lastMousepos = Input.MousePosition;
    }
    else
    {
        AxisX = ((Input.MousePosition.x - lastMousepos.x) / Time.deltaTime) / Screen.Width;
        AxisY = ((Input.MousePosition.y - lastMousepos.y) / Time.deltaTime) / Screen.Height;
        lastMousepos = Input.MousePosition;
    }}
```

AxisX и AxisY выдает скорость движения от 0 до 1 по каждой оси. 1 - скорость, при которой мышка пролетает весь экран за кадр.